# How to block a ListPreference dialog from opening when that ListPreference was clicked on?

Tags: java, android, listpreference

I've got a `ListPreference` in which I can select items and set parameters for purposes. When I click on it in my Settings Fragment where all of my `Preferences` are, it opens a dialog and lets me choose the items listed in it. I am using two handlers, `OnPreferenceClickListener` (Called when I click on my `ListPreference`) and `OnPreferenceChangeListener` (Called when I select an item in it).

I want to block the dialog from opening without disabling the `ListPreference` at all so that I cannot select the items in it. I've blocked changing the items with a global `boolean` in my `OnPreferenceChangeListener`.

```
boolean canChange = true;

final ListPreference listPreference = (ListPreference) findPreference("myListPreference");

listPreference.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {

        canChange = myCondition;
        return true;
    }
});

listPreference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {

        if(canChange)
            someValueHolder = listPreference.findIndexOfValue(newValue.toString());

        return true;
    }
});
```

This is a bad code but the best attempt I could think of to avoid changing the listed items if `myCondition` is `false`. But I want to know how I can block the Dialog from popping up when I click on the preference if `myCondition` is `false` and instead open up a dialog with a warning message like `You cannot change this ListPreference when myCondition is false!`?

Comment: Have you found solution for that?